# Bigquery CASE function not working as expected

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a list of brand_name and need to use CASE + REGEX to match them to different brand_type.

However bigquery does not seem to be classifying the brand_name correctly as expected, i.e everything that should fall under the "Else" case gets classified to "Furniture"

here's a just a simplified query to show the logic being used:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(brand_name, r"pen|scissors")= TRUE THEN 'Stationery'
WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(brand_name, r"chair|table")= TRUE THEN 'Furniture'
WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(brand_name, r"cup|pot")= TRUE THEN 'Household'
ELSE 'Stationery'
END AS brand_type FROM table
```

e.g expect paper to be classified as "Stationery" but it is classified as "Furniture" instead:

| id | brand_name | brand_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | pen | Stationery |
| 2 | chair | Furniture |
| 3 | cup | Household |
| 4 | paper | Furniture |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below instead

```
SELECT CASE 
  WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(brand_name, r"pen|scissors") THEN 'Stationery'
  WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(brand_name, r"chair|table") THEN 'Furniture'
  WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(brand_name, r"cup|pot") THEN 'Household'
  ELSE 'Stationery'
END AS brand_type 
FROM table
```

As you can see, you had extra `CASE` which broke the logic.
Also you do not need to use `=TRUE`

Comment: hey sorry it's my bad, that was the typo i made when posting. my original query is the same as yours

Comment: if this would be true - you would get `paper` as `Stationery` . look carefully into your real query to find the difference!!

Comment: i think it could be due to `=TRUE`, i removed that and the query works now. it's a silly mistake, thanks!